# Syncing OneDrive in fixed intervals instead of constantly

Tags: sync, onedrive, scheduling

Sometimes during work, I generate and delete hundreds of temporary files that end up in different directories.
The directories are being synced with OneDrive, which ends up constantly shoving these temporary files around unnecessarily.

Is there a way to set OneDrive to only run e.g. once per hour?

If not, is there a way of excluding files other than the clunky GUI, like a simple list of file name patterns to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

You can try syncing OneDrive regularly using **Task Scheduler**. The steps are as follows:

1. Search for task scheduler, and then open the Task Scheduler app in the search results.
2. Select Action in the taskbar, then click Create Task.
3. Then configure your OneDrive sync task, such as naming the task and adding a description, and selecting security options.
4. Go to Triggers > New, then select the sync frequency you need or set a specific time to sync OneDrive.
5. Then return to the Create Task window and confirm the OneDrive schedule sync settings, and then click OK to confirm.

You can also try syncing on demand.

1. Right-click the OneDrive icon and click Settings
2. Select Folders in the account
3. Check the folders you want to sync in the pop-up dialog box.

[image]